# How do I read 数 in ページ数?

Tags: kanji, pronunciation, compounds

ページ数 means number of pages. Is it すう or かず?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「ページ数」 is always read 「ページ**すう**」.

***Generally*** speaking, 「数」 is read 「かず」 when preceded by originally Japanese words, and it is read 「すう」 when preceded by Sino- and Non-Sino loanwords.  Be reminded that exceptions abound regarding this matter.  When unsure, consult a dictionary or call me collect.

> **「かず」:**

「[口数]{くちかず}」(talkativeness), 「[場数]{ばかず}」(number/amount of experience(s) ), 「[品数]{しなかず}」(number of items), etc.

> **「すう」:**

「ホームラン数」(number of homeruns), 「[台]{だい}数」(number of machines, cars, etc.), 「[支店]{してん}数」(number of branches for a company), 「ゴール数」(number of goals in soccer), etc.

> ***A Hillarious Exception:***

「[頭数]{あたまかず}」: The number of ***people*** in a given place or situation.

「[頭数]{とうすう}」: The number of ***(larger) animals*** in a given place or situation.

Answer (score 6):

It is read すう in this case

- [From Tangorin](http://tangorin.com/general/%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E6%95%B0): 
  PEEJIsuu
- [From Weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E6%95%B0)
  読み方：ページすう